# IF Statement in Coldfusion

Tags: stored-procedures, if-statement, coldfusion

I have a form in coldfusion file and I want to put in a if statement to check that some fields have text in them before they get sent into a stored procedure. So an if statement to check form fields are not null, if they are then some sort of text to say "please enter data"...

I want to put the if statement around this block of code...

```
    <CFSTOREDPROC PROCEDURE="InsertOfficeLocation" DATASOURCE="#application.servernamesql02#">
<CFPROCPARAM VALUE="#country#" TYPE="IN" CFSQLTYPE="cf_sql_varchar" VARIABLE="@Country">
<CFPROCPARAM VALUE="#address#" TYPE="IN" CFSQLTYPE="cf_sql_varchar" VARIABLE="@Address">
<CFPROCPARAM VALUE="#address2#" TYPE="IN" CFSQLTYPE="cf_sql_varchar" VARIABLE="@Address2">
<CFPROCPARAM VALUE="#address3#" TYPE="IN" CFSQLTYPE="cf_sql_varchar" VARIABLE="@Address3">
<CFPROCPARAM VALUE="#address4#" TYPE="IN" CFSQLTYPE="cf_sql_varchar" VARIABLE="@Address4">
<CFPROCPARAM VALUE="#city#" TYPE="IN" CFSQLTYPE="cf_sql_varchar" VARIABLE="@City">
<CFPROCPARAM VALUE="#postcode#" TYPE="IN" CFSQLTYPE="cf_sql_varchar" VARIABLE="@PostCode">
<CFPROCPARAM VALUE="#receptionnumber#" TYPE="IN" CFSQLTYPE="cf_sql_varchar" VARIABLE="@ReceptionNumber">
<CFPROCPARAM VALUE="#mainnumber#" TYPE="IN" CFSQLTYPE="cf_sql_varchar" VARIABLE="@MainNumber">
<CFPROCPARAM VALUE="#faxnumber#" TYPE="IN" CFSQLTYPE="cf_sql_varchar" VARIABLE="@FaxNumber">
<CFPROCPARAM VALUE="#username#" TYPE="IN" CFSQLTYPE="cf_sql_varchar" VARIABLE="@Username">
<CFPROCPARAM VALUE="#timestamp#" TYPE="IN" CFSQLTYPE="cf_sql_varchar" VARIABLE="@Timestamp">    
    </CFSTOREDPROC>
```

Comment: What problem did you run into when you tried it? (Side note: That kind of validation should be done beforehand. ie Do not mix it with the `cfstoredproc` code)

Comment: You are not using the variable name correctly.  ColdFusion does not support named parameters.  You have to send your parameters in the order the stored proc expects them.

Comment: @Leigh this is what i have atm: <CFIF IsNull("Form.country")>   But i dont know how to return some sort of message in the form to say "Please enter a value"....

Comment: @DanBracuk the parameters are in order and it works, just need to put the check in for empty form values

Comment: @user3032507 - `IsNull` is used for something different. Form fields are never null. The result of leaving a field empty, or not making a selection, depends on the field type. With text fields, the field will always exist, but will contain an empty string. So you need to check the `len(FORM.yourField)`. Fields like radio buttons/checkboxes/*multiple* select lists will *not* exist. You can check if it was omitted by using `<cfif structKeyExists(FORM, "theNameOfTheFormField")> do something</cfif>`.

Comment: Also not related to your question, but varchar for a variable called timestamp?   This sounds most unwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands with the code you've shown us so far and how you've phrased your question, you should only need to do something like:

```
<cfif len(form.country) AND len(form.address) ...>
  <cfstoredproc >...</cfstoredproc>
<cfelse>
  Please enter all fields
</cfif>
```

Although I'd probably want to do something better than that, e.g. different error messages for each field.  Or using the NULL attribute on the cfprocparam to pass through null values for empty fields for instance.

Also you say these are form values; it's a good idea to scope your variables with the relevant scope.

PS: you only need to specify the `variable` attribute on `<cfprocparam>` when the type is OUT or INOUT

Comment: To clarify, the `variables` attribute does not mean what you think it does. It is **not** being used to say "populate the stored procedure variable `@country` with the value in `#country#`. (CF used to have that functionality via a different attribute ie `dbvarname`. But as Dan mentioned, it is now deprecated.) The `variable` attribute is only used for SQL `OUT` parameters. It allows the stored procedure to populate a variable and return it back to the calling page in CF.

Comment: @Leigh - oops, I said type=IN when I obviously meant OUT... thanks for your comment

Comment: @user3032507, no offence, but simply extend my example code to include each of the fields you're interested in surely?  `<cfif len(form.country) AND len(form.address)  AND len(form.City) AND len(form.ReceptionNumber)>`